# App Flutter error "(nameOfMyApp) keeps stopping)"

Tags: android, flutter, emulation

When I do flutter run in console of Android Studio this appears in the console (not only that but if I paste all the "E/AndroidRuntime" this post will be huge):

E/AndroidRuntime(12699): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(12699): Process: com.brfideliza, PID: 12699
E/AndroidRuntime(12699): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.brfideliza/com.brfideliza.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.brfideliza.MainActivity" on path
: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~oZyd_niv09UNr4TWVjJGtA==/com.brfideliza-C_GViHORaEdaenjVuV846g==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~oZyd_niv09UNr4TWVjJGtA==/com.brfideliza-C_GViHORaEdaenjVuV846g==/lib/x86_64, /dat
a/app/~~oZyd_niv09UNr4TWVjJGtA==/com.brfideliza-C_GViHORaEdaenjVuV846g==/base.apk!/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]

And when I try to run the app in the Android Emulator, the app closes instantly and shows "(nameOfMyApp) keeps stopping"

I tried to do flutter clean/flutter pub get.

I tried too to change the android:name="${applicationName}" to android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication" but when I did that, it caused error "Build failed due to use of deprecated Android v1 embedding."

And my flutter doctor don't have issues.